# Basic / conceptual issues, query performance with Cypher and Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm doing a project on credit card fraud, and I've got some generated sample data in .CSV (pipe delimited) where each line is basically the person's info, the transaction details along with the merchant name, etc.. Since this is generated data, there's also a flag that indicates if this transaction was fraudulent or not.

What I'm attempting to do is to load the data into Neo4j, create nodes (persons, transactions, and merchants), and then visualize a graph of the fraudulent charges to see if there are any common merchants. (I am aware there is a sample neo4j data set similar to this, but I'm attempting to apply this concept to a separate project).

I load the data in, create constraints, and them attempt my query, which seems to run forever.

Here are a few lines of example data..

```
ssn|cc_num|first|last|gender|street|city|state|zip|lat|long|city_pop|job|dob|acct_num|profile|trans_num|trans_date|trans_time|unix_time|category|amt|is_fraud|merchant|merch_lat|merch_long
692-42-2939|5270441615999263|Eliza|Stokes|F|684 Abigayle Port Suite 372|Tucson|AZ|85718|32.3112|-110.9179|865276|Science writer|1962-12-06|563973647649|40_60_bigger_cities.json|2e5186427c626815e47725e59cb04c9f|2013-03-21|02:01:05|1363831265|misc_net|838.47|1|fraud_Greenfelder, Bartoletti and Davis|31.616203|-110.221915
692-42-2939|5270441615999263|Eliza|Stokes|F|684 Abigayle Port Suite 372|Tucson|AZ|85718|32.3112|-110.9179|865276|Science writer|1962-12-06|563973647649|40_60_bigger_cities.json|7d3f5eae923428c51b6bb396a3b50aab|2013-03-22|22:36:52|1363991812|shopping_net|907.03|1|fraud_Gerlach Inc|32.142740|-111.675048
692-42-2939|5270441615999263|Eliza|Stokes|F|684 Abigayle Port Suite 372|Tucson|AZ|85718|32.3112|-110.9179|865276|Science writer|1962-12-06|563973647649|40_60_bigger_cities.json|76083345f18c5fa4be6e51e4d0ea3580|2013-03-22|16:40:20|1363970420|shopping_pos|912.03|1|fraud_Morissette PLC|31.909227|-111.3878746
```

The sample file I'm using has about 60k transactions

Below is my cypher query / code thus far.

```
 USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "card_data.csv"
 AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'


 CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(line.cc_num), name_first: line.first, name_last: line.last })
 CREATE (m:Merchant { id: line.merchant, name: line.merchant })
 CREATE (t:Transaction { id: line.trans_num, merchant_name: line.merchant, card_number:line.cc_num, amount:line.amt, is_fraud:line.is_fraud, trans_date:line.trans_date, trans_time:line.trans_time })

 create constraint on (t:Transaction) assert t.trans_num is unique;
 create constraint on (p:Person) assert p.cc_num is unique;

 MATCH (m:Merchant)
 WITH m
 MATCH (t:Transaction{merchant_name:m.merchant,is_fraud:1})
 CREATE (m)-[:processed]->(t)
```

You can see in the 2nd MATCH query, I am attempting to specify that we only examine fraudulent transactions (is_fraud:1), and of the roughly 65k transactions, 230 have is_fraud:1.

Any ideas why this query would seen to run endlessly? I do have MUCH larger sets of data I'd like to examine this way, and the small data results thus far are not promising (I'm sure due to my lack of understanding, not Neo4j's fault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show any index creation. To speed things up, you should create an index on both `merchant_name` and `is_fraud`, to avoid going through all transaction nodes sequentially for a given merchant:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Transaction(merchant_name)
CREATE INDEX ON :Transaction(is_fraud)
```

Comment: Thanks David! That worked, though now I'm not quite seeing what I expected. I have a central node which is a fraudulent transaction (and only 1 of the 230 fraud transactions), connected to 25 other nodes of type merchant, with the same name..

What I was hoping to see was merchants associated with fraudulent transactions.. so ideally one or two merchants as central nodes, connected to all fraudulent transactions that occurred at the given merchant.

Maybe that's not what my query is asking for?

Comment: Link to image - http://i.imgur.com/43ZUw8h.png

Central node is fraudulent Tx, blue nodes appear to be repetition of the same merchant (same name, different "id" value).

Answer (score 0):

You create duplicate entries both for merchants as well as for people.

```
// not really needed if you don't merge transactions
// and if you don't look up transactions by trans_num
// create constraint on (t:Transaction) assert t.trans_num is unique;

// can't a person use multiple credit cards?
create constraint on (p:Person) assert p.cc_num is unique;

create constraint on (p:Person) assert p.id is unique;
create constraint on (m:Merchant) assert m.id is unique;




USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "card_data.csv" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'


MERGE (p:Person { id: toInt(line.cc_num)})
   ON CREATE SET p.name_first=line.first, p.name_last=line.las
MERGE (m:Merchant { id: line.merchant}) ON CREATE SET m.name = line.merchant

CREATE (t:Transaction { id: line.trans_num, card_number:line.cc_num, amount:line.amt, merchant_name: line.merchant,
        is_fraud:line.is_fraud, trans_date:line.trans_date, trans_time:line.trans_time })

CREATE (p)-[:issued]->(t)

// only connect fraudulent transactions to the merchant
WHERE t.is_fraud = 1
// also add indicator label to transaction for easier selection / processing later
SET t:Fraudulent     
CREATE (m)-[:processed]->(t);
```

Alternatively you can connect all tx to the merchant and indicate the fraud only via label / alternative rel-types.